# Unity3D & Realsense 2.0 D415 - Depth to Terrain

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, realsense

I am trying to generate a runtime terrain from the depth values of the RealSense camera D415.
I got the camera to try and do something for the summer.  I never used more than webcams in Unity before so I'm very lost even after going through all the sample scenes.

My terrain is 500 x 500 x 40
using RealSense SDK 2.0
the terrain generator code is below which works with Perlin noise

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using Intel.RealSense;

/// <summary>
/// this script is made to test the new terrain in unity with intel realsense depth
/// </summary>
public class TerrainGenerator : MonoBehaviour {

    public int depth = 40;
    public int width = 500;
    public int height = 500;

    public float scale = 20f;

    public float xOffset = 10;
    public float yOffset = 10;
    private DepthFrame depthFrame;
    public bool scroll;
    public float scrollSpeed;

    private Pipeline pipe;
    private void Start()
    {
        ///
        pipe = new Pipeline();
        pipe.Start();


        ///


        xOffset = Random.Range(0f, 9999f);
        yOffset = Random.Range(0f, 9999f);

        scroll = false;
        scrollSpeed = 0;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        Terrain terrain = GetComponent<Terrain>();
        terrain.terrainData = GenerateTerrain(terrain.terrainData);

        if(scroll)
            xOffset += Time.deltaTime * scrollSpeed;

    }
    TerrainData GenerateTerrain(TerrainData tData)
    {
        tData.heightmapResolution = width + 1;
        tData.size = new Vector3(width, depth, height);
        tData.SetHeights(0, 0, GenerateHeights());
        return tData;
    }
    float[,] GenerateHeights()
    {
        float[,] heights = new float[width, height];
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {

                //heights[x, y] = CalculateHeight(x, y);
                var frames = pipe.WaitForFrames();
                var depth = frames.DepthFrame;
                heights[x, y] = depth.GetDistance(x, y);

            }
        }
        return heights;
    }

    float CalculateHeight(int x, int y)
    {
        //float xCoord = (float)x / width * scale + xOffset;
        //float yCoord = (float)y / height * scale + yOffset;
        //return depthFrame.GetDistance(x,y);
        //return Mathf.PerlinNoise(xCoord, yCoord);

        using (var frames = pipe.WaitForFrames())
        using (var depth = frames.DepthFrame)
            return depth.GetDistance(x, y);
    }

}
```

I am looking for some guidance on how to init the camera depth properly. I have never used a camera before with Unity.

Answer (score 1):

Bit off-topic but I wanted to ask how well your above code runs? Are you getting errors such as:

`ExternalException: rs2_pipeline_wait_for_frames(pipe:000000006402E3C0)
Rethrow as Exception: Frame didn't arrived within 1000`

I'm trying to do something similar and also having problems. Maybe we can work it out together?

Cheers,
Cam

Comment: You should probably make this into a comment instead, since it doesn't really answer the user's question (although it still could be helpful)

Comment: I would love to, but I need 50 rep before I'm able to do that! Couldn't see any other way of messaging the user. Any ideas?

Comment: Here's a potentially helpful Meta question about comments https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174. As far as things I'd recommend, I'd say get your feet wet answering some questions that you can handle, or if you have some good questions ask those (but don't ask questions just for the sake of asking)

Comment: I feel like I am being discouraged from using this site so I will look elsewhere.

Comment: On the contrary @CamAtlantic, we want you to spread your knowledge and help others! If you don't feel comfortable getting reputation on StackOverflow, you can try any number of the other [StackExchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites); by getting 200 repuation on another StackExcahnge site, you will [get +100 reputation on all other sites for being a trusted member](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238)!

Comment: HI Cam,
the code above is not really meant to run. it will throw an error with the real sense pipeline. but if u change to use only the perlin noise to generate the heights then it will run on a terrain game object. 
I would love to continue this project. I picked it up as something to do over the summer, which is now over but I surely would love to collaborate to make something cool. The new RS SDK though has been a real struggle for me.